# Maximize and Minimize windows in Mac (keyboard only)

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm coming from linux and found the way to set up KB shortcuts and the whole system a bit alien.

I do not seem to find a way to just minimize and maximize windows using the keyboard only on MacOS. I read the documentation and also asked chatGPT which in the end recommends a paid app for this simple task.

I have also tried to set up "Application launch" keyboard shorts but even though they are set, nothing happens (with many applications, Firefox, Terminal, etc.)

How do you achieve this?

Comment: You can Minimise with Cmd/M, but as soon as you do that the window becomes de-focussed so there's no way to bring it back. Personally, I gave up years ago using minimise at all & instead use Spaces. For app launch, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/460089/85275